# How to set my Bluetooth python script on higher priority than Ubuntu's request?

Tags: server, python, scripts, bluetooth

I have got a Bluetooth Python Server Script on Ubuntu to connect with an incoming request from a Smartphone device. However Ubuntu's Bluetooth is getting the request before my script can react on it. How can I set my Script on 1st priority?

Simple Server Script:

```
import bluetooth

server_sock=bluetooth.BluetoothSocket( bluetooth.RFCOMM )

port = 1
server_sock.bind(("",port))
server_sock.listen(1)

client_sock,address = server_sock.accept()
print "Accepted connection from ",address

data = client_sock.recv(1024)
print "received [%s]" % data

client_sock.close()
server_sock.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I was able to solve that problem!

1. Kill the Bluetooth-Applet:

   ```
   sudo killall bluetooth-applet
   ```
2. For PIN-Pairing set sspmode to 0:

   ```
   sudo hciconfig hci0 sspmode 0
   ```
3. I opened the simple-agent, so you can edit the code if you want to:

   ```
   sudo -H gedit /usr/local/bin/simple-agent
   ```
4. Start simple-agent:

   ```
   su -c /usr/local/bin/simple-agent
   ```